# Resampling with date and hour ranges

Tags: python, bigdata, etl, dask, resampling

I am trying to resample a dataframe and compute aggregated values. During the resampling process, I want to be able to exclude:

- specific time ranges during each day, format: `%H:%M:%S`
- specific days during the period, format `%YYYY-MM-DD`

```
def _ohlc(
        trades_df,
        price_col_name,
) -> dd.DataFrame:
    # Extract the prices column from the trades df
    prices_df = trades_df[price_col_name]

    # Resample trades into OHLC format of specified frequency
    resampled_prices_df = prices_df.resample(f'1S')  # <-- This line produces a row for each second
    ohlc = resampled_prices_df.ohlc()

    # Forward fill prices
    filled_ohlc = ohlc.ffill()

    return filled_ohlc
```

What is the fastest/most efficient way to achieve a resampled dataframe, excluding specified intraday time range and date range?

There are a couple of answers on stack that are simply too slow.
Looping over values via `.apply()` simply takes too much time. I'm currently using Dask, for processing - but at this point any efficient solution with any library is appreciated.

**Context:**
Trying to compute OHLCV data from Trades data, excluding the times during a day where the market is closed and the days when the market are closed (holidays)

**Considerations:**

- The df index is of type `datetime64[ns]`
- The raw file has over 10B rows, data doesn't fit into memory.
- If possible, I want to avoid non-vectorized operations because of cost concerns.

Comment: [Vaex](https://pypi.org/project/vaex/) might be a suitable alternative to Pandas and Dask for your use case.

Comment: Check out this for ideas [Lesson 4. Resample or Summarize Time Series Data in Python With Pandas - Hourly to Daily Summary](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/use-time-series-data-in-python/date-time-types-in-pandas-python/resample-time-series-data-pandas-python/)